# Mutable global state causing issues with array length

Tags: reactjs, react-state-management, react-easy-state

I've been working on a SPA for a while and managing my global state with a custom context API, but it's been causing headaches with undesired rerenders down the tree so I thought I'd give react-easy-state a try. So far it's been great, but I'm starting to run into some issues which I assume has to do with the mutability of the global state, something which was easily solved with the custom context api implementation using a lib like immer.

Here's a simplified version of the issue I'm running into: I have a global state for managing orders. The order object `primaryOrder` has an array of addons into which additional items are added to the order - the list of available addons is stored in a separate store that is responsible for fetching the list from my API.  The orderStore looks something like this:

```
const orderStore = store({
  initialized: false,
  isVisible: false,
  primaryOrder: {
    addons: [],
  }
})
```

When a user selects to increases the quantity of an addon item, it's added to the addons array if it isn't already present, and if it is the `qty` prop of the addon is increased. The same logic applies when the quantity is reduced, except if it reaches 0 then the addon is removed from the array. This is done using the following methods on the orderStore:

```
const orderStore = store({
  initialized: false,
  isVisible: false,
  primaryOrder: {
    addons: [],
  },
 get orderAddons() {
    return orderStore.primaryOrder.addons;
  },
increaseAddonItemQty(item) {
    let index = orderStore.primaryOrder.addons.findIndex(
      (i) => i.id === item.id
    );

    if (index === -1) {
      let updatedItem = {
        ...item,
        qty: 1,
      };
      orderStore.primaryOrder.addons = [
        ...orderStore.primaryOrder.addons,
        updatedItem,
      ];
    } else {
      orderStore.primaryOrder.addons[index].qty += 1;
    }
    console.log(orderStore.primaryOrder.addons);
  },
  decreaseAddonItemQty(item) {
    let index = orderStore.primaryOrder.addons.findIndex(
      (i) => i.id === item.id
    );

    if (index === -1) {
      return;
    } else {
      // remove the item from the array if value goes 1->0
      if (orderStore.primaryOrder.addons[index].qty === 1) {
        console.log("removing item from array");
        orderStore.primaryOrder.addons = _remove(
          orderStore.primaryOrder.addons,
          (i) => i.id !== item.id
        );
        console.log(orderStore.primaryOrder.addons);
        return;
      }
      orderStore.primaryOrder.addons[index].qty -= 1;
    }
  }
})
```

The issue I'm running into has to do with the fact that one of my views consuming the `orderStore.addons`.  My `Product` component is the consumer in this case:

```
const Product = (item) => {
    const [qty, setQty] = useState(0);
    const { id, label, thumbnailUrl, unitCost } = item;

    autoEffect(() => {
        if (orderStore.orderAddons.length === 0) {
            setQty(0);
            return;
        }
        console.log({ addons: orderStore.orderAddons });
        let index = orderStore.orderAddons.findIndex((addon) => addon.id === id);
        console.log({ index });
        if (index !== -1) setQty(orderStore.findAddon(index).qty);
    });

    const Adder = () => {
        return (
            <div
                className="flex"
                style={{ flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: "space-between" }}
            >
                <div onClick={() => orderStore.decreaseAddonItemQty(item)}>-</div>
                <div>{qty}</div>
                <div onClick={() => orderStore.increaseAddonItemQty(item)}>+</div>
            </div>
        );
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div>{label} {unitCost}</div>
            <Adder />
        </div>
    )
}

export default view(Product)
```

The issue occurs when I call `decreaseAddonItemQty` and the item is removed from the `addons` array.  The error is thrown in the `Product` component, stating that `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined` due to the fact that the array length reads as 2, despite the fact that the item has been removed ( see image below)

[image]

My assumption is that the consumer `Product` is reading the global store before it's completed updating, though of course I could be wrong.

What is the correct approach to use with react-easy-state to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you found an auto batching bug. Just wrap your erroneous mutating code in `batch` until it is fixed to make it work correctly.

```js
import { batch, store } from '@risingstack/react-easy-state'

const orderStore = store({
  decreaseAddonItemQty(item) {
    batch(() => {
      // put your code here ...
    })
  }
})
```

Read the *"Reactive renders are batched. Multiple synchronous store mutations won't result in multiple re-renders of the same component."* section of the repo readme for more info about batching.

**And some insight:**

React updates are synchronous (as opposed to Angular and Vue) and Easy State (and all other state managers) use React `setState` behind the scenes to trigger re-renders. This means they are all synchronous too.

`setState` usually applies a big update at once while Easy State calls a dummy setState whenever you mutate a store property. This means Easy State would unnecessarily re-render way too often. To prevent this we have a `batch` method that blocks re-rendering until the whole contained code block is executed. This `batch` is automatically applied to most task sources so you don't have to worry about it, but if you call some mutating code from some exotic task source it won't be batched automatically.

We don't speak about `batch` a lot because it will (finally) become obsolete once Concurrent React is released. In the meantime, we are adding auto batching to as many places as possible. In the next update (in a few days) store methods will get auto batching, which will solve your issue.

You may wonder how could the absence of batching mess things up so badly. Older transparent reactivity systems (like MobX 4) would simply render the component a few times unnecessarily but they would work fine. This is because they use getters and setters to intercept get and set operations. Easy State (and MobX 5) however use Proxies which 'see a lot more'. In your case part of your browser's `array.splice` implementation is implemented in JS and Proxies intercept get/set operations inside `array.splice`. Probably `array.splice` is doing an `array[2] = undefined` before running `array.length = 2` (this is just pseudo code of course). Without batching this results in exactly what you see.

I hope this helps and solves your issue until it is fixed (:

Edit: in the short term we plan to add a strict mode which will throw when store data is mutated outside store methods. This - combined with auto store method batching - will be the most complete solution to this issue until Concurrent React arrives.

Edit2: I would love to know why this was not properly batched by the auto-batch logic to cover this case with some tests. Is you repo public by any chance?

Comment: Thanks @Bertalan, I never considered using batching within the method because, as far as I understood it from reading the docs, batching is used when updating more than one state property.  I'd love to help work out why this happens.  Just an FYI, I solved the issue before seeing your response by passing the addons array to the container as props and wrapped it in cloneDeep. I assume this meant that the props only updated once the internal updating was complete, as opposed to accessing the store diectly from inside the component.